# find_digit is not defined in Pylance - PYTHON

Tags: python

class TimeUtil():

```
def calculate_seconds(self, input):
    if any(x in input.lower() for x in ['weeks', 'week','wks','wk']):
        return (int(find_digit(self, input))*604800)        
    elif any(x in input.lower() for x in ['days', 'day']):
        return (int(find_digit(self, input))*86400)
    elif any(x in input.lower() for x in ['hours', 'hour','hr','hrs']):
        return (int(find_digit(self, input))*3600)
    elif any(x in input.lower() for x in ['minutes', 'minute','min','mins']):
        return (int(find_digit(self, input))*60)
    elif any(x in input.lower() for x in ['seconds', 'second','sec','secs']):
        return (int(find_digit(self, input))*60)
    else:
        return -1

def find_digit(self, text):
    return ''.join(input for input in text if input.isdigit())
```

By calling find_digit method in another method calculate_seconds I could see the error as "find_digit is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVaribale)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the way your calling `find_digit()` is like that:

```
find_digit(self, input)
```

You probably meant to write it like that:

```
TimeUtil.find_digit(self, input)
```

but you should write it like that because it's more readable:

```
self.find_digit(input)
```